# Rails set attribute with looping one-liner

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to define a Model attribute.

Can you do this in one line?

```
d = []
item.xpath("feature").each {|i| d << i.text}
product.description = d.join(", ")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
product.description = item.xpath("feature").map(&:text).join(", ")
```

Comment: Now that sure is purty